# Config http request spring mvc and angular js?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, http-headers

I have this service that I published on my local machine:

```
http://joediego.dtdns.net:3000/jcsistemas/rest/cliente/all
```

If I hit afromentioned URL endpoint, I can get a response with my JSON feed. But when I use another host name such as *http://localhost:8081*, the service responds with below message:

```
XMLHttpRequest can not load http: // localhost: 8081 / jcsistemas / rest / customer / all. In the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin "header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http: // localhost: 9000' is not allowed Therefore access.
```

Here is what I tried so far to overcome the same origin policy issue:

```java
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
//filter 
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}
    public void destroy() {}
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("my..package...... ")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    //configureContentNegotiation
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(true).
              ignoreAcceptHeader(true).
              useJaf(false).
              defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
              mediaType("html", MediaType.TEXT_HTML).
              mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    }
}
```

AngualarJS Module configuration:

```js
angular.module('my_module').config(['$routeProvider','$httpProvider',function($routeProvider,$httpProvider) {
    //how configure headers here??    
    }]);
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by removing `@Component SimpleCorsFilter` and adding `getServletFilters()` method in a `WebApplicationInitializer` subclass. For to those who use a Java-based application configuration, here down the component declaration:

```java
public MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer 
{
    @ Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() 
    {
        return new Filter[] {new MyFilter()}; // MyFilter refers to the filter needed class
    }
}
```